# jQuery .each() and CodeMirror

Tags: jquery, each, codemirror

I'm creating CodeMirror textareas in many different tabs and I need to loop through the textareas in the tab that's being created on a click. I have found the elements, that's the textareas that I need to convert. I'm trying to use jQuery `.each()` to go through them and convert to CodeMirror:

```
var queryBuilder = $(tabPanelDiv).find(".QueryBuilder");
queryBuilder.each(function(index, el) {            
    var editorQuery = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(el)[index], {
         lineNumbers: true,
         tabMode: "indent",
         mode: "text/x-sql",
         theme: "eclipse"
    });
    queryArr.push(editorQuery);
});
```

The problem that I'm having is my lack of experience with `.each()` and how to insert the element into `CodeMirror.fromTextArea()`. In this `.each()` the conversion works for the first textarea but the second one always goes to CodeMirror code as undefined. I have all the 5 textareas but I'm using the `index, el` parameters the wrong way. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore `index`. Inside `each`, the `el` argument *is* the correct element at that index, the `index` argument is simply so you can be aware of where you are in the set you're iterating over.

You should be simply using `el`, not `$(el)[index]`:

```
queryBuilder.each(function(index, el) {            
    var editorQuery = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(el, {
      ...
    });
    queryArr.push(editorQuery);
});
```

Also, because you're turning one array (of elements) into another array (of CodeMirror objects) you should be using [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), not `each`:

```
var queryArr = queryBuilder.map(function(index, el) {            
    return CodeMirror.fromTextArea(el, {
      ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx that was it. I thought I had tried just to have the el parameter but I probably had $ in front of it or something. Thx for the tip with map, I'll try to use that instead.